# install subversion on windows

Tags: windows, svn

I'm looking for idiot-proof instructions for installing the SVN server on windows. In terms of configuration all I need to do is to create a user that can connect from the local machine.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out visualsvn server http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Comment: VisualSVN is about the easiest you're going to find.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [ultra express easy guide to install SVN from CodingHorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001093.html). I've used it many times without hesitating or having any issues.

Comment: +1 for actually answering Don's question instead of providing him links to GUI SVN interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Answer (score 2):

I second the responses that say VisualSVN Server. It's incredibly easy to install and use with a small footprint, and integrates well with Windows Server or even desktops with Active Directory support. It includes an integrated Apache server to provide web access to the repository, and can be run over HTTPS/SSL (with a self-signed cert) for secure remote use.

Answer (score 1):

We use the [Tigris.org build of SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows) for the server and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) for the client, with [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for a web tracking presence. It's worked quite well for our small group of 10 developers.

If you're looking for instructions, there are [plenty of howto's on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=subversion+on+windows).

Comment: +1 for Tigris.org and TortoiseSVN.  We been running them for the last year without issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's several good alternatives now days:

Free:

CollabNet Subversion - http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

VisualSVN Server - http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Commercial:

PainlessSVN - http://www.painlesssvn.com

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) reasonable. It's probably also the most official, as it's linked to from subversion's main page. The book's server seems to be down at the moment, but hopefully it will be back soon.